# Escaping % in python mysql execute

Tags: python, mysql

The escaped date format

```
load_data = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s INTO TABLE table1
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '' (@ADate)
  SET ADate = 
  IF(@ADate = '', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(@ADate,'%%c/%%e/%%Y %%h:%%i:%%s %%p'))"""
cur.execute(load_data, (ed_file,))
```

keeps triggering on execute line:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

```
create table table1 (ADate datetime);
ed_file could be empty single line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using two parameters for file name and string date format:

```
load_data = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s 
               INTO TABLE table1
               FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
               ESCAPED BY '' (@ADate)
               SET ADate = IF(@ADate = '', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(@ADate, %s))
            """

dt_format = '%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'

cur.execute(load_data, (ed_file, dt_format))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I have found a workaround. replace %%s with %%S since both equivalent and big S works.
%S  Seconds (00 to 59)
%s  Seconds (00 to 59)